# Can we Copy & Paste node modules?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, libxml-js

Normally we supped to use "npm" to install node modules. However, one of the node module in our projectis [libxmljs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs)
This module has two issues
1> The version (v 0.17.1) cannot be installed on windows machine.  [Issue392](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/issues/392)
2> It needs VS 2013 or 15 to build [Issue 393](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/issues/393)

The first we resolved by lower down the version from 0.17.1 to 0.16.1.
Now for the second issue my development machine has VS 2013 installed. So i was able to install libxmljs on my development machine. However on web server we dont want to have VS installed. I was wondering will it work if just copy "node_modules\libxmljs" folder from development machine to web server?

Comment: If the module is compiled, in that case I think it is compiled, you can copy if you have the same architecture in both machines.

Comment: @EduardoPereira When you say architecture , you meant 32 bit vs 64 bit OS, right?

Comment: Yeah, 32 and 64, maybe it can work even with different arch, but I'm not sure, maybe you can try the copy stuff and post your experience here.